# Customizing an application for tablet - any suggestions?

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience, tablet

I have an application developed for android phone. Now I am going to customize it to be used on tablet (Galaxy Tab). Assuming I have to redesign some screens and flows for better user experience, are there any tips/things to be aware of/etc. you can share?

Thanks

PS. I am aware of this: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could checkout HoneyCombs new Fragment API

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-30-fragments-api.html

This allows you to have new view called a component it can be used like a self contained activity but the highlight is you can use multiple fragments on the screen at once, for better flow in your UI.

They are also trying to make it backwards compatible with non tablet devices so you can keep supporting your other users!

Comment: Btw I don't think the Galaxy Tab supports 3.0 yet :-) Although Samsung have said they're working on it!

Comment: Yes so I wouldn't recommend changing your code too dramatically for this one tablet with 2.2. Bear in mind Google suggested tablet manufacturers waited for 3.0 to release tabs but Samsung just didn't listen.